# add an array to another array in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have a strange problem because "addObject" is working to add an `NSString` but not to add an `NSArray`:

```
    NSMutableString *starCatalogEntryValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; // a single string from a catalog
    NSMutableArray *starCatalogEntryData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // array of strings
    NSMutableArray *starCatalogData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // array of arrays

loop i times {
    [starCatalogEntryData removeAllObjects];
    loop j times {
        [starCatalogEntryData addObject:starCatalogEntryValue]; // This works
    }
    [starCatalogData addObject:starCatalogEntryData]; // This does not work
}
```

Actually, adding the array `starCatalogEntryData` works but not properly. I end up with i entries in `starCatalogData` but they are all equal to the last value of `starCatalogEntryData`.

Comment: You need a refresher course on what an object is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you reuse `startCatalogEntryData` over and over. You want this:

```
NSMutableString *starCatalogEntryValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; // a single string from a catalog
NSMutableArray *starCatalogData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // array of arrays

loop i times {
    NSMutableArray *starCatalogEntryData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // array of strings
    loop j times {
        [starCatalogEntryData addObject:starCatalogEntryValue]; // This works
    }
    [starCatalogData addObject:starCatalogEntryData]; // This does not work
}
```

This creates a new array each time.

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem. Can you explain why the "removeAllObjects" did not work?... I think I'm seeing something I missed before, the actual object is added to the array, not copied to the array, so I have create the new object each time! As you can tell I've just started OOL. Thanks again.

Comment: When you call `[starCatalogData addObject:startCatelogEntryData]`, no copy is made. You simply add a reference to the entry array. So when you add it a second time, you have now added two references to the same array. So when you call `removeAllObjects`, it removes all objects from the one array that has two references (not copies) of the array. This is why you need a completely new array each time.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. This has been a real demystifier!